# Nestjs read file from assets directory

Tags: nestjs

I'm using nestjs 8. I want to access and read file from assets directory.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFile('assets/audio/sound-1.mp3')
```

With this code it doesn't find the file.

How can I access resource file from assets directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the path to the assets directory from the dist? Where is the assets directory located?

Comment: It's a nestjs project. It's the default path under project/src/assets

Comment: So what's the path to `project/src/assets` from the `dist`?